# Randomly occuring: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependencies

I am working on an ASP.NET (.NET 4.7) project and I'm constantly getting the following error when I change completely irrelevant part of my app:

`Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.`

If I uninstall `System.Reflection` and reinstall it (using NuGet) the problem goes away... only for a few minutes. I change something else in code (nothing to do with Reflection or no NuGet package adding/removing, just some C# or HTML code), restart my app, and the error comes again.

Why is it happening randomly and how do I get rid of this?

**UPDATE**: I've deleted all the `bin` and `obj` folders from the whole solution countless of times. No avail.

Comment: the error indicates that one of your dll wasn't updated to Net 4.7.  I would close project and then make copy of project bin folder and delete bin folder.  This will force project to rebuild all source files.

Comment: @jdweng my bad, forgot to mention that. already did them all.

Comment: Are there other dlls in the Bin folder.  The issue may be in another project.  The dlls will tell us if other project dlls are being referenced.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue - in my case it was a problem with nuget restoring to packages from older .net versions which I was unable to solve. Ended up upgrading to the new VS 2017 [csproj](http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/) format and therefore the new nuget, and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Change 4.7 to 4.7.1 and it is fixed.

Comment: it seems to work, but I need to be sure that it won't fire up the same error randomly in the future.